# How do you add Ctrl-T information to a program?

Tags: unix, terminal, progress

When you press ctrl-t when dd(1) is running it tells you how much data it transfered and how long it has been running.  If you press it during a cp(1) you can see which file it is up to and the percent done copying.

I'd like to add the same type of feature to my program.  How can I do that?

Comment: ctl-t generates an INFO signal.  You can put a signal handler in your code to catch the signal and print your info.

Comment: Note that SIGINFO is a BSD thing which does not exist on Linux (a pity, really, as it is quite handy in case you need to quickly check what's up with the current app.)